# Bootcamp interrupted; now stuck on Windows boot looking for startup

Tags: bootcamp

I have a MBP with Yosemite (10.10.5 I think). I was trying to install Windows 7 from a USB and cancelled it when it got stuck looking for a driver - I don't have any disk drive and that seemed to confuse it; there didn't seem to be an option to go back or cancel so I think I just powered down by holding down the power button.

Now when I try to startup it seems to be stuck in Windows mode looking for a bootable device.

Is there a key combination that will make it reset back to starting in Mac OS?

Comment: Did you try press and hold the _option_ key at boot to bring up the  Startup Manager?  See: [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) and [How to choose a startup disk on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417)

Comment: Thanks, that did it (holding down the option key at bootup).  You should put it in as an answer and I'll mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bring up the Startup Manager, press and hold the option key immediately after you turn on your Mac and hear the startup sound.

For additional information see: [Startup key combinations for Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) and [How to choose a startup disk on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204417).